# See render progress in VSE

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

I have several scenes in strips in the VSE. When I use the VSE to render I get the results I want but I cannot see the frames as they are rendering the same way I do when I render directly from the scenes themselves (not the VSE scene where all the clips are brought together). They only appear after the frame is completely rendered.

Is there any way to render everything from the VSE and see the progress as it renders in the Image Viewer like you do in a single scene?

Hope this makes sense - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That just depends on what you set your Display to in your Render Properties:

[image: Display Property]

Set it to *Image Editor*, *Full Screen* or *New Window* to see the result as it's being rendered.

Though you have to keep in mind that Frames that originate from a Movie Clip, Video Strip or Image Strip won't be rendered partially but as a whole image anyways. So you will only see real rendered images that originate from a 3D scene.